# How to redirect output to a file in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, redirect, cmd, output

In Windows 7, I have a batch file that runs an exe in the sub-directory of bat file, it first changes current directory to that folder, then runs the exe. But something goes wrong, I see a console window for a very short time and the program doesn't start. Since the output console is displayed for less than a second, I can't see the error message.

bat file is:

```
cd /d "%~dp0my_subfolder"
start "" myapplication.exe
```

How do I redirect the output error message to a text file (the text file will be in the same directory with bat file), so that I can read the error message? What command should I add to the bat file above?

Comment: Not an answer to the question as asked, but as a workaround for the underlying problem you could try adding the `pause` command after the batch's last command to be able to read the output in the console window before it disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
 start "" myapplication.exe > mytextfile.txt 2>&1
```

instead you could run batch file from cmd to know what is the error

Comment: Do I need to specify full path of text file?

Comment: It's optional. If you donot specify the path, file would be created at "%~dp0my_subfolder".

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't write anything to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to see the error message:

```
cd /d "%~dp0my_subfolder"
start "" /b myapplication.exe
pause
```